# Not understanding why this program isn't working?

Tags: c

The program I'm making is supposed to print strings out that only end in 'ed'. This is what I have so far, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.  Am I misunderstanding the logic behind the for loop with the if statement or am i just going about this wrong completely?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{ 
    char string[10][100]; 
    int i; 

    for ( i =0; i<=10; i++)
    { 
       printf(" Please enter a string for the array \n"); 
       fgets( string[i], 100, stdin); 
    } 

    int length = strlen(string[i]); 

    for ( i=0; i<=10; i++)
    { 
       if( string[i][length] == 'd' && string[i][length -1] == 'e' )
       { 
          printf(" Index %d: %s \n", i,  string[i]); 
       }  
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

thanks for all the input guys! However, the program is still not outputting strings that end in'ed' when i enter them through the keyboard, it compiles just fine. Here's what I have modified:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () 
{ 
  char string[10][100]; 
  int i;
  int length;

  for ( i =0; i < 10; i++)
  { 
     printf(" Please enter a string for the array \n"); 
     fgets( string[i], 100, stdin); 
  } 

  for ( i=0; i< 10; i++)
  { 
     length = strlen(string[i]); 

     if( length > 1 && (string[i][length - 1] == 'd' && string[i][length -2] == 'e') )
     { 
        printf(" Index %d: %s \n", i,  string[i]); 
     }  
  } 

  return 0;     
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself this question: "What is the value of `length` for each iteration of the loop?"

Comment: This is a poor title and description. Instead of "doesn't work", explain what is actually happening, and what you expected to happen instead. Make the title reflect this.

Comment: You need to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. It will help you more than us just giving you the solution.

Comment: As for your edit, ***carefully*** read: http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets

Comment: Just figured it out. I was misunderstanding the index of each string. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Your indices are not correct.  In C, indices start with 0.  The first loop should be:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
```

The indices in second loop are also not correct.  They should be:

```
int length = strlen ( string[i] );
if( length > 1 && ( string[i][length-1] == 'd' && string[i][length -2] == 'e' ) )
```

In the above statement, since the indices start at 0, the last element will be at `length-1`.  If your string is `smiled`, the character at index 0 is `s` and the last character is at index 5 (`d`) while the length of string is 6.

Comment: And it should also be checked that `length >= 2` to avoid pointing out of the array.

Comment: and please do not declare a variable in loops, you should declare the length variable outside the loop (even if the latest compilers allow it, it's still a bad practice)

Comment: Though your answer is correct I find it difficult to read (too concise). It will be perfect if you elaborate a little more. Do keep in mind that he seems to be new to C.

Comment: I tried modifying it like you said, however i'm still unable to output strings that end in 'ed'. The program compiles just fine but does not output anything.

Comment: That is because `fgets` will add the newline character at the end of the string.  So, you either have to remove that, or look for `length-2` and `length-3`.

Comment: @Lectem Concerning "do not declare a variable in loops":  Consider passing your suggestion on to the committee that drafted the C spec and tell them their usage of that style is bad practice.

Comment: +1 for a proper test of `length > 1`.  Minor: better to use `size_t  length`.

Comment: @Lectem why is it bad practice?

Comment: I should have rephrased as "it's bad for newbie in C to be shown this"
He obviously doesn't have a good understanding of how arrays (therefore pointers) and variables works, and he is bound to make mistakes because of the variable reach if he starts declaring variables in loops